# Retrieve the last entered ID

Tags: laravel

I need to retrieve the ID just entered from this query which records the follow in the database, I have already tried as follows but it doesn't work.

https://github.com/overtrue/laravel-follow

```
$follow = $request->user()->follow($user);
return $follow->id;
```

Comment: The `follow()` function doesn't return what you're assuming it does. It only returns an array containing `['pending' => $isPending]`, https://github.com/overtrue/laravel-follow/blob/b7d6c870b1b437122b37499e2f0fce7170dec388/src/Followable.php#L45

Comment: Is there no way to recover the newly created id then?

Comment: You'd have to poke around. It appears you could grab `$request->user()->followings()->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->first()`. Might want to do it in a transaction to prevent race conditions. There may be other ways; I'm not familiar with the package, but don't just guess what a function returns like this.